# Why would my additional information harm my prediction score but improve ROC and F-1?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, roc, f1

I'm trying to predict the primary crime type on a given location using the [Chicago crime dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/chicago/chicago-crime).

Stripping out all the provided features to just:

- Location Description Encoded (The location information like street, house, apartment - label encoded)
- Beat (An int representing the police patrol route)

And only trying to predict from the types, label encoded:

- Narcotics
- Battery

Yields the highest score against the predictions of about 75% using a DecisionTreeClassifier.

What I did to try and improve on this score, was to include crime cluster information.

For each community area in Chicago (there are 77), I divided each into 10 clusters (using K-Means). Then, for each cluster - I got a percentage for each of my target feature crimes out of all the crimes in the cluster e.g.

```
Cluster has 100 crimes

BATTERY_CLUSTER_PERCENT = 0.25
THEFT_CLUSTER_PERCENT = 0.15
NARCOTICS_CLUSTER_PERCENT = 0.05
OTHER_CLUSTER_PERCENT = 0.55
```

And I assigned each of these values to every row for that cluster.

When I went back and tried my model with these features, the score appears to have actually dropped by a percent.

This is my model **without** the cluster information

[image]
[image]
[image]

And **with** the cluster information added in:

```
print(f'DecisionTreeClassifier Score: {model.score(X_test, y_test)}')
DecisionTreeClassifier Score: 0.747892534416884
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

What's interesting is that my F-1 score increased as well as my ROC.

Why might this happen? Is there anything I can do to improve my score or is this a totally wrong approach?

Comment: It sure looks like the situation where you’ve got the higher AUC also has the higher accuracy. Please explain why you think your model with higher accuracy has lower AUC.

Comment: I'm confused why `model.score(X_test, y_test)` is outputting (ever so slightly) lower scores, I would have expected some improvement rather than consistently a tiny bit lower...

Comment: I don’t follow what you’re doing. Which numbers confuse you.

Comment: See the values for `DecisionTreeClassifier Score: 0.747892534416884`? That's the output from `model.score(X_test, y_test)` - it's nearly the same when including or excluding the cluster information. Is there a reason why the model accuracy wouldn't have increased to 0.80 for example?

Comment: But then what’s the 65% that you mentioned?

Comment: crap sorry that's a typo - both scores are coming out around 75%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106899/discussion-between-dave-and-tomselleck).